# Loop through a JS array and place the React component appropriately

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a few react components (for eg:like below)

```
import AloneTab from './tab/AloneTab'
import BiTab from './tab/BiTab'
import CalTab from './tab/CalTab'
import DelTab from './tab/DelTab'
```

I have an array `obj={"Alone":true,"Bi":true,"Cal":false,"Del":true}`

Currently, I am rendering the components inside a `div` like so (just a representation)

```
<div>
 {obj["Alone"]? <AloneTab/>: null}
 {obj["Bi"]? <BiTab/>: null}
 {obj["Cal"]? <CalTab/>: null}
 {obj["Del"]? <delTab/>: null}
</div>
```

3 components will render ( will not render since `"Cal":false`)

I have just shown only a few components but there are many more & repeating the code again & again is not nice. Is there a way to loop over the items & renders the components?

I tired

```
const keys=  Object.keys(obj)
const values=  Object.values(obj)

const tabs = keys.map((tab, index)=>
        values[index] ? <`${tab}Tab`/> :null)

<div>
 {tabs}
</div>
```

However, this does not work. Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of making this work is to store the component within the object and associate it with the relevant key. Store this along with the boolean value of whether or not it should be shown.
Please see below:

```js
// ./TabOne.js
export default function TabOne() { return <div>Tab One</div>; }
// Repeat for TabTwo, TabThree and TabFour
```

```js
// App.js
import TabOne from "./TabOne.js";
import TabTwo from "./TabTwo.js";
import TabThree from "./TabThree.js";
import TabFour from "./TabFour.js";

export default function App() {
  const data = {
    "one": { "show": true, "content": <TabOne /> },
    "two": { "show": false, "content": <TabTwo /> },
    "three": { "show": true, "content": <TabThree /> },
    "four": { "show": false, "content": <TabFour /> }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        Object.keys(data).map(key => {
          return data[key].show 
            ? <div key={key}>{data[key].content}</div> 
            : null
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above returns:

```
Tab One
Tab Three
```